# Google Places API returns wrong results

Tags: google-places-api

This issue seems to have started today (2016-08-10) and is still ongoing as of this post. As of yesterday, the places api was returning correct results.

There seem to be 2 locations that are being inserted into api requests for all coordinate requests, these are:

1. HÃ´tel de Ville (Paris) (48.856924,2.3526841)
2. University of Illinois at Chicago Hospita (Chicago) (41.8696656,-87.6704474)

These places are added to all requests, no matter what coordinates or radius are provided.

Anyone else experiencing this, or is it some setting that I have enabled that is including these places by default?

This is the API in use
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search

Comment: Faced the same problem since yesterday.....seemed like the results were returned no matter what the query

Comment: Bug has been fixed, invalid results are no longer there as of now.

Comment: Just to close the loop- this was tracked as: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10283

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug, the same results came back from a request near the origin: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-0.75,-0.75&radius=100&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Please file a bug in the Google Maps API issue tracker:
https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Places%20API%20-%20Bug

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Bug submitted.